# Assign MAC address to a veth pair

Tags: linux, namespace

I have created 6 namespaces and configured them with veth links. I'm trying to attach MAC address. But the following error is shown :

```
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address
```

Here is my code :

## Add namespaces

```
ip netns add ns1
ip netns add ns2
ip netns add ns3
ip netns add ns4
ip netns add ns5
ip netns add ns6
```

## Add veths

```
ip link add eth0 type veth peer name eth1
ip link add eth2 type veth peer name eth3
ip link add eth4 type veth peer name eth5
ip link add eth6 type veth peer name eth7 
ip link add eth8 type veth peer name eth9
```

## link veths

```
ip link set netns ns1 eth0
ip link set netns ns2 eth3
ip link set netns ns3 eth6
ip link set netns ns4 eth9
ip link set netns ns5 eth1
ip link set netns ns5 eth2
ip link set netns ns5 eth4
ip link set netns ns6 eth5
ip link set netns ns6 eth7
ip link set netns ns6 eth8
```

## assign mac's

```
ip netns exec ns1 ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 
ip netns exec ns2 ifconfig eth3 hw ether 03:03:03:03:03:03 
ip netns exec ns3 ifconfig eth6 hw ether 06:06:06:06:06:06
ip netns exec ns4 ifconfig eth9 hw ether 09:09:09:09:09:09
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: it is failing for any address

Comment: When debugging, or asking for help, reduce the problem to the simplest form. In this case, instead of doing 10 interfaces, do just 1. Provide details on that. Show the status of the interface within the namespace, show the error message after the command which generated it, not at the top of the question, etc.

Comment: And BTW, instead of figuring out the format of a valid MAC address, you can also just keep the MAC addresses that get assigned automatically - unless you want to do something that requires specific MAC addresses, but it that case you probably would have tried with valid ones.

Answer (score 4):

There is no namespace issue. There is no veth (virtual ethernet) type issue. The only issue is the [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details) chosen:

`00:00:00:00:00:00` is most certainly reserved for things like "unset" and thus invalid

Any address with the [multicast bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet) (least-significant bit of the first octet) set can't be a card's hardware address: a multicast address can be only a *destination* address, not *source*, so this makes no sense to assign it to a card. So strike those:

```
03:03:03:03:03:03
09:09:09:09:09:09
```

Remaining valid ethernet MAC address:

`06:06:06:06:06:06` which even has the [local bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Universal_vs._local) (second least significant bit of the first octet) set, which is preferable for tests and virtualization (but technically not mandatory at all).

As was said in comments, it's probably better to just keep those already randomly, and correctly, generated. If they are needed, just retrieve their value for later use (including reusing them later for complete reproducibility).